# MoveIt! groovy symbol lookup error (KDL plugin)

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I generate a arm motion planning package as described in the [setup assistant](http://moveit.ros.org/moveit_setup_assistant.html) tutorial and try to start things according to the [rviz plugin](http://moveit.ros.org/motion_planning_rviz_plugin.html) tutorial:

```
roslaunch move_group.launch
```

I get the following:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group_action_server: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/groovy/lib//libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10kdl_parser17treeFromUrdfModelERKN4urdf14ModelInterfaceERN3KDL4TreeE
[move_group-1] process has died [pid 15385, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group_action_server __name:=move_group __log:=/home/kohlbrecher/.ros/log/6d4c5a32-54cc-11e2-abe3-9439e59a9133/move_group-1.log].
log file: /home/kohlbrecher/.ros/log/6d4c5a32-54cc-11e2-abe3-9439e59a9133/move_group-1*.log
```

This is on Ubuntu 12.04/64bit with Groovy and MoveIt! installed from .deb packages. Any hints on how to make things work are greatly appreciated.

On a related note, the [links to issue trackers](http://moveit.ros.org/reporting_issues.html) on the MoveIt! website are all down, it would be helpful if they work.

Also, what is the general state of MoveIt! at the moment? There was a disclaimer on the website with a warning that it will be released with groovy which disappeared now. OTOH there hasn't been a public announcement yet and the partly outdated tutorials and dead links on the website also look more like things are still in development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51308/moveit!-groovy-symbol-lookup-error-(kdl-plugin)/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Stefan,

Thanks for reporting these issues! As you noticed we have not made a public announcement about the MoveIt release. This is because we are still working on things. This is mostly tutorials and documentation (for the initial release). We are also developing code in parallel, but the core things are there.
The current webpage is in the process of being replaced with a wiki that is more up to date, and more complete. We will make an announcement when we believe we have a version ready for release.

As for the errors you mentioned, I fixed the broken links and I was able to replicate the missing symbol problem you pointed out. I put it in this ticket:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/issues/121

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-01-03**:
issue just got fixed